# Looking for memory efficient outer product sum

Tags: python, numpy

I have an equation of the form:

[image]

where a and b are 1D arrays of size n and m. I want to avoid forming anything of size n*m in an intermediate step because n and m are both very large the memory needed will be too expensive.

One solution is a simple python loop:

```
total = 0
for j in range(n):
    total += a[j] * b**j
```

I'm looking for a native numpy solution without a python loop. But to solve without a python loop I can't find a numpy function that will work without forming the n by m array of [0*b, b, b**2, b**3, ...] as an input.

Edit:

As hpaulj pointed out a polynomial solution might work. I found this:

```
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial
total = polynomial.polyval(b, a)
```

This gives the same values in a quick test, and according to the notes on polyval it uses Horner's method and appears to be optimal. My actually problem is a sum over two dimensions but I think this solution will generalize.

Edit 2:

polyval seems to cause a

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply c0 = c[-i] + c0*x
```

at smaller array sizes than even np.outer causes a MemoryError. When it does work it is much faster than the python loop.

Edit 3:

Ignore Edits 1 & 2. The following runs faster (on my machine) with the python loop. `polyval` does at least seem to be memory efficient.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial
a_size = 3
b_size = 6
a = np.random.rand(10**a_size)
b = np.exp(2j * np.pi * np.random.rand(10**b_size))
start = time.time()
c = polynomial.polyval(b, a)
middle = time.time()
print(middle - start)
c2, b_current = 0, b**0
for i in range(0, a.size):
    c2 += a[i] * b_current
    b_current *= b
end = time.time()
print(end-middle)
```

Comment: So the result is the same size as `b`? What's the relative sizes of n and m? You could iterate on the smaller one.

Comment: hpaulj, you are correct, the output is the size of b. a should generally be the smaller array.

Comment: This just a n degree polynomial?

Comment: hpaulj, good point, I'll edit question to show a possible solution.

Comment: Do you need `a` later in the code?

Comment: wwii, no `a` does not need to be used again.

Comment: The runtime warning is an arithmetic overflow, not a memory overflow. What dtype are a and b?

Comment: @tls-chris, good point, I choose some unfortunate arrays for the test. I've retested with `b` as phases and `a` as random values. I'll add a third edit.

Comment: If you found your own solution, please post it as an answer and not (only) an edit to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found anything faster than the original python loop.